# what is the first non-constant term in the Kronecker Limit formula?

Tags: cv.complex-variables

The Kronecker Limit formula gives the constant term in the Laurent expansion about s=1 of the Eisenstein series E(s,\tau). What is the next term? I.e., the coefficient of the first power of (s-1)? I saw a paper on this, published in the 1940's (I think), but I cannot find it. I would appreciate any help in this.

Comment: Please do not simultaneously crosspost here and on MSE.

Comment: And if you do post something to both websites, include a link at each one to the other one. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042476/what-is-the-next-term-in-the-kronecker-limit-formula